# É certo receber votos contra antes de tirar dúvidas sobre a pergunta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, voto-contra

Fiz um [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97486/como-receber-valor-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-de-outra-classe/97489?noredirect=1#comment197930_97489) e um dia, depois de obter uma resposta e interagir por comentário, recebi comentários negativos por usuários que não entenderam a pergunta.

Vi o perfil deles e constatei que eles não tinham nenhuma tag relacionada com as minhas (não dominam a linguagem da minha pergunta).

Outro usuário já me ajudou por comentário, agora ele queria colocar uma resposta mas está como PENDENTE. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Se você recebeu negativos, já foram removidos por quem tinha votado, após sua última edição. Estou reabrindo a pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto desculpe, nao forma negativas, foi que acharam confusa.. mas já estava interagindo com outros usuários..

Comment: A não ser que a pessoa diga "votei negativo", *não tem* como você saber quem votou o que. E também, votar negativo é uma forma de forçar o autor a melhorar a pergunta e também de avisar outros usuários "pergunta com problemas à frente".

Comment: Ele confundiu os termos. Na verdade foram votos para fechar, porque era uma pergunta de uma frase (e confusa/ampla), mas o problema foi resolvido e a pergunta reaberta pelo bfvaretto. A pergunta não recebeu (até o momento) votos positivos ou negativos.

Comment: Sou novo aqui, realmente me confundi.. mas agradeço a atenção.. o que eu quis dizer é que quem leu a pergunta e viu as tags [Swift] [IOS] [MVC ] entendeu o que eu quis dizer.. quem votou como confusa estava acostumado com [C] [PHP] [Java], sabemos que cada linguagem tem sua particularidade.. se eles acharam confusas acredito que deveriam ter questionado antes, só isso.
Obrigado pelo suporte

Comment: Fábio você não entendeu o motivo dos votos de fechamento, fechar ocorre realmente quando a pergunta não esta clara ou carece de algo e o motivo deste fechamento é pra evitar respostas que podem ser erradas devido a pergunta não estar clara, gerando um trabalho de colaboração desnecessário, talvez esta postagem que fiz lhe ajude a entender: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu justamente não entendi o motivo do fechamento porque quem estava com dúvida não fez nenhum comentário, eu editei a pergunta diversas vezes e mesmo assim parece que eles simplesmente abandonaram.. só acho certo votar para fechamento sem ao menos fazer um questionamento.. mas enfim, agradeço o suporte de todos

Comment: Uma coisa que você deve levar em consideração é que se algo parece que esta claro pra ti não significa que vai ficar claro a todos, levando em consideração que a tua duvida não tem código que possa *ser reproduzido*, dificilmente alguém entendiaria bem o que você necessita, claro que existem exceções, note que nem todo mundo aqui terá a capacidade de responder sobre diversas linguagens, o melhor é que em um periodo você não conseguiu nenhuma resposta que lhe ajude, você poderá jogar uma recompensa na pergunta, leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: mas @GuilhermeNascimento, a pergunta ja estava sendo respondida, o mínimo que eles poderiam fazer é pedir mais detalhes ou esclarecimentos.. na minha opinião..

Comment: Fábio, por favor entenda, fechamento não é algo negativo pra ti, é algo pra prevenir problemas pra comunidade. Sendo assim, considere que as perguntas aqui não são apenas suas mas sim da comunidade e você deve levar em consideração que a pergunta deve ser útil a comunidade também. Quanto mais clara melhor. Se a pergunta foi editada e esta clara, então basta votar pra reabrir, se ela realmente estiver boa depois da sua edição então é só esperar que ela vai passar por uma triagem na **fila de analise** (aonde apenas usuários com 5k podem acessar) e eles irão avaliar...

Comment: ... Se receber 3 de 5 votos pra reabrir então irá reabrir, se receber 3 votos pra manter fechada então é porque a pergunta ainda tem problemas. Espero que entenda o sistema do site :) Se tiver alguma duvida sobre como funciona as ferramentas do StackOverflow me pergunte! Até mais Fábio!

Comment: Entender eu entendo, mas acho que faltou por parte deles questionar, mas obrigado mais uma vez pelo suporte e atençao.

Comment: Fábio entendo que o pessoal poderia ter questionado um pouco mais, no entanto o site aqui não é um fórum, nos fóruns geralmente debatemos até entender a necessidade do autor da pergunta, aqui o intuito do site é pergunta e resposta. Quando a pergunta é fechada no rodapé aparece o motivo, então o autor deve apresentar um esforço minimo pra tentar seguir a dica do rodapé, note que somos todos humanos e pode haver situações que o fechamento foi um engano e por isto existe a **fila de analise**....

Comment: ... gostaria que você olha-se estes links: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/3635 - Espero que entenda que aqui são muitas perguntas diariamente e o autor da pergunta é quem mais deve se esforçar pela própria pergunta, mas claro que outros usuários podem não obrigatoriamente ajudar a tornar a sua pergunta mais clara. Espero que entenda que aqui ninguém faz nada por mal, mas sim pelo bem do site :) Se você sentir que o fechamento foi "injusto" então venha aqui no META e provavelmente receberá auxilio de como melhorar (se for possivel)

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez Guilherme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É certo, sim. Não tem problema em receber votos negativos e de suspensão da pergunta antes de esclarecimentos formais do AP (autor da pergunta).
O voto em si é um pedido de esclarecimento, e além disso serve de sinalização a outros usuários/visitantes que a pergunta não está bem formulada para os padrões do site e que precisa ser melhorada ou fechada/deletada.

Não conheço a linguagem/tecnologia envolvida mas como programador sei do que está falando. E como frequentador de vários sites da rede, sei o que constitui uma pergunta mal formulada. Creio que a primeira versão da pergunta é *extremamente* pobre, minha primeira reação seria votar negativo, votar para [fechar](/help/closed-questions) como "não está claro o que está perguntado" e deixar um comentário orientador (ou votar o comentário de alguém que já fez isso):

> #### Como receber valor de uma variável de outra ViewController
>
> Tenho uma variável na ViewController1 e quero utilizar essa variável em uma função na ViewController2

Se quer ir diretamente à solução do seu problema (em vez do drama de votos negativos, votos para fechamento e comentários pedindo esclarecimento), forneça todos os detalhes necessários de primeira: contexto, código relevante, informação de debug, etc.

Como norma geral, sempre que comentamos uma pergunta de usuários sem experiência no site, pedimos que leiam a Central de Ajuda, especialmente a seção [***Perguntando***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Tendo essas informações básicas entendidas, não tem mistério: é só escrever a pergunta detalhada e aguardar respostas de gente muito boa de serviço. Quando a gente pede ajuda de outras pessoas que vão *doar* seu tempo e conhecimento, nosso trabalho é deixar tudo muito bem claro e explicado.

Comment: Caro @brasofilo, não fiz  nenhum drama por causa disso.. o que eu quiz dizer, e que parece que ninguém entende é que NINGUEM DEIXOU COMENTARIO pedindo esclarecimento ou alguma duvida sobre a pergunta.. niguem fez o que voce mesmo disse que iria fazer

votar para fechar como "não está claro o que está perguntado" e deixar um comentário orientador (ou votar o comentário de alguém que já fez isso)

Minha pergunta já estava sendo respondida, enfim.. eu ja agradeci todo o suporte dado, já entendi como funciona o site.. também não entendi o porque escrever o que já foi explicado..

Comment: @FábioReibnitz basicamente ele postou uma resposta, pois até o momento não tinhamos nenhuma (comentários são voláteis, afinal de contas). Lembre-se que a resposta não é exclusiva para você, mas uma referência para todos os usuários do site. E diz respeito ao problema como um todo, não só à ocorrência específica do seu caso. Futuramente o link desta resposta pode ser até postado como referência para outros com as mesmas dúvidas, facilitando o acesso à informação.

Comment: @FábioReibnitz Trata-se do que disse o Bacco. Uma vez alguém posta uma pergunta, ela é licenciada à Stack Overflow e deixa de ser "minha/sua". Publiquei a resposta para referência futura... desculpe por categorizar como "drama", isso não era dirigido a sua pessoa mas ao tipo de situação que perguntas mal-formuladas provocam. Saudações!

Comment: Blz @Bacco, tudo certo!